# How do I delimit Property bag values so search treats them as individual searchable words?

Tags: development, ssom

Currently I am using the property bag with values that are comma separated something like:

```
web.AllProperties["fruits"] = "bananas, apples, oranges, tomatoes";
```

Currently search is treating them as one search word and I am wondering which delimiter I am using for search to use them as individual searchable words when indexed or if it is even possible this way ?

Comment: I don't think exist a solution with delimeters. You have to create a property for each value. Ex: myproperty1, myproperty2, mypropertyN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a complete list of the different types of fruit (or whatever object) you want to search then you could use managed metadata and set up a custom termset.

Answer (score 1):

The property bag is simply a hash table. You could start with an array and iterate it in order to add a property for each item. Then add a property for Fruit:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
$fruitsArray = @("fruit","bannana","apple","orange");
foreach ($i in $fruitsArray)
{
    web.AllProperties["MyFruitTerm" + [array]::IndexOf($fruitsArray,$i)] = $i;
    web.IndexedPropertyKey.Add($i);
}
web.Update();
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```